# Why banner admob show only black ? Even i use admob test id. (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, admob

I use admob_flutter package. And i want to show admob banner in bottom screen. So why my banner only show black even i use admob test id.

This is the package i use in my flutter project

```
admob_flutter: ^1.0.1
```

And this the source code to show banner admob

```
class BannerAdmobWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldState;
  final double bannerHeight;
  final double bannerWidh;
  final AdmobBannerSize bannerSize;
  final Function(AdmobAdEvent event) listener;

  const BannerAdmobWidget({Key key,this.listener, this.scaffoldState,this.bannerSize= AdmobBannerSize.LARGE_BANNER, this.bannerHeight=100, this.bannerWidh=320}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _BannerAdmobWidgetState createState() => _BannerAdmobWidgetState();
}

class _BannerAdmobWidgetState extends State<BannerAdmobWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance
    .addPostFrameCallback((_) => showSnackBar(content: "Load Banner Admob",scaffoldState: widget.scaffoldState));
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: widget.bannerHeight,
      width: widget.bannerWidh,
      child: AdmobBanner(
        key: ValueKey("BannerAdmob"),
        adUnitId: getBannerAdUnitId(),
        adSize: widget.bannerSize,
        listener: (AdmobAdEvent event,Map<String, dynamic> args) {
          widget.listener(event);
        },
        onBannerCreated: (AdmobBannerController controller){
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[this is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5KJL.png)